# g++ " undefined reference to `typeinfo for xercesc_3_2::XMLException" on Linux

Tags: linux, gcc, g++

I encountered the following error when using `g++` and `xercers` to compile a package.

```
/home/201999800003/YangFan/gcc/bin/g++ -o gcam.exe -O2 -pthread -ggdb -DNDEBUG -DFUSION_MAX_VECTOR_SIZE=30  -MMD -std=c++14 -Wno-deprecated -Wl,-rpath,/home/201999800003/xerces-c-3.2.3/src/xercesc/lib:/home/201999800003/xerces-c-3.2.3/src/xercesc/dom:/home/201999800003/xerces-c-3.2.3/src/xercesc/util -Wl,-rpath,    main.o -lgcam  -L/usr/local/lib -L/home/201999800003/xerces-c-3.2.3/src/xercesc/lib:/home/201999800003/xerces-c-3.2.3/src/xercesc/dom:/home/201999800003/xerces-c-3.2.3/src/xercesc/util -L/home/201999800003/YangFan/gcam-core/cvs/objects/build/linux -L   -lxerces-c -ljvm -L/home/201999800003/boost_1_75_0/stage/lib -Wl,-rpath,/home/201999800003/boost_1_75_0/stage/lib -lhector -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem   -lm 
/home/201999800003/YangFan/gcam-core/cvs/objects/build/linux/libgcam.a(scenario.o):(.gcc_except_table+0x3bc): undefined reference to `typeinfo for xercesc_3_2::XMLException'
/home/201999800003/YangFan/gcam-core/cvs/objects/build/linux/libgcam.a(scenario.o):(.gcc_except_table+0x424): undefined reference to `typeinfo for xercesc_3_2::DOMException'
/home/201999800003/YangFan/gcam-core/cvs/objects/build/linux/libgcam.a(scenario.o):(.gcc_except_table+0x428): undefined reference to `typeinfo for xercesc_3_2::XMLException'
/home/201999800003/YangFan/gcam-core/cvs/objects/build/linux/libgcam.a(scenario.o): In function `_ZN9XMLHelperIvE13safeTranscodeB5cxx11EPKDs':
/home/201999800003/YangFan/gcam-core/cvs/objects/containers/source/../../util/base/include/xml_helper.h:709: undefined reference to `xercesc_3_2::XMLPlatformUtils::fgMemoryManager'
/home/201999800003/YangFan/gcam-core/cvs/objects/containers/source/../../util/base/include/xml_helper.h:709: undefined reference to `xercesc_3_2::XMLString::transcode(char16_t const*, xercesc_3_2::MemoryManager*)'
/home/201999800003/YangFan/gcam-core/cvs/objects/containers/source/../../util/base/include/xml_helper.h:711: undefined reference to `xercesc_3_2::XMLPlatformUtils::fgMemoryManager'
/home/201999800003/YangFan/gcam-core/cvs/objects/containers/source/../../util/base/include/xml_helper.h:711: undefined reference to `xercesc_3_2::XMLString::release(char**, xercesc_3_2::MemoryManager*)'
```

I think it's because my environment variables for `xercers` is improper. The error info says I have used `lxerces-c`. So my issue is different from some others I found through google.

Especially, I doubt I set wrong `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Before, I tried `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/201999800003/xerces-c-3.2.3/src/xercesc/lib` No success

So I set
`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/201999800003/xerces-c-3.2.3/src/xercesc/lib:/home/201999800003/xerces-c-3.2.3/src/xercesc/dom:/home/201999800003/xerces-c-3.2.3/src/xercesc/util`.
Because I saw the error info says `XMLException` and this file is in the directory `/home/201999800003/xerces-c-3.2.3/src/xercesc/util`

I searched around and did not find any concrete answer on how to set the environment variable.

Sorry I am a new to Linux and also C++. Can anyone please give me a hint on how to solve this problem?

Many thanks!

## update

I tried installing another version `xerces3.1.1` and compiled the package again, and it popped up exact the same error message `typeinfo for xercesc_3_2::XMLException`. Is it normal?

I also check `config.log` of `xerces`. Despite xerces is configured successfully, some variables showed undefined in the config.log

```
/home/201999800003/xerces-c-3.2.3/conftest.cpp:116: undefined reference to `clock_gettime'
/home/201999800003/xerces-c-3.2.3/conftest.cpp:137: undefined reference to `wcsupr'
ACLOCAL='${SHELL} /home/201999800003/xerces-c-3.2.3/config/missing aclocal-1.16'
AUTOCONF='${SHELL} /home/201999800003/xerces-c-3.2.3/config/missing autoconf'
AUTOHEADER='${SHELL} /home/201999800003/xerces-c-3.2.3/config/missing autoheader'
AUTOMAKE='${SHELL} /home/201999800003/xerces-c-3.2.3/config/missing automake-1.16'
MAKEINFO='${SHELL} /home/201999800003/xerces-c-3.2.3/config/missing makeinfo'
```

Comment: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is for loading shared libraries at ***runtime***, and should bear no relevance on the linker's search path.

Comment: Thanks a lot @SamVarshavchik. I also changed `XERCES_LIB`, which caused the change in linker search `-L/home/201999800003/xerces-c-3.2.3/src/xercesc/lib:/home/201999800003/xerces-c-3.2.3/src/xercesc/dom:/home/201999800003/xerces-c-3.2.3/src/xercesc/util`. Is this change valid? The `XMLException.cpp` file is in the directory `/home/201999800003/xerces-c-3.2.3/src/xercesc/dom`. How should I change environment variables to add other directors in linker search?

Comment: With most compilers, the `-L` option names one directory, and multiple `-L` options get used to specify multiple directories. Additionally, in which directory a particular `.cpp` file exists bears no direct relevance on any linking error due to an undefined reference.